# How to use a ResX file to batch translate list columns in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, localization, resx

I'm trying to use ResX Resource Manager (RRM) to batch translate list columns in SharePoint Online.

Something's not working as I expected and I'm not sure where I went wrong. I'm using SharePoint in M365 and the standalone version of ResX Resource Manager.

My SharePoint site's default language is set to "French". I've added "English" as a secondary language.

I used SharePoint's Export translations function to export the French text. This downloads a ResX file named "[site_name].fr-FR.resx" in my Downloads folder. I'm removed the localization tag (fr-FR) from the filename so RRM recognizes it as the neutral language resource file.

I opened ResX Resource Manager and set my neutral language as French (France) (fr-FR). I set the source to my Downloads folder.

I added a column for English (United States) and started translating. This created a new file named "[site_name].fr-FR.en-US.resx" in my Downloads folder.

I used SharePoint's Import translations function to import the en-US resx file. I didn't get an error message.

Unfortunately, when I ask a colleague's whose regional language settings are set to English to check if the translation is showing, they're still seeing the French column headers inside my list.

Help!